# CMake Hierarchical Project Management Without Abusing Libraries

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have a project where there's only a handful of logical groupings for generating static libraries. However for convenience I want to have the library's source code to be managed with more granular folders.

Currently the only way I know to do this in CMake without having a library for each folder is to just list files as you would normally in with their relative paths:

```
add_library(SystemAbstraction STATIC "Some/Path/File.cpp")
```

However I can see this getting unwieldy as the project grows in size with all the different paths.

I tried to see if I could have a CMakeLists.txt in each folder and just use a variable in the base CMakeLists.txt when adding library dependencies. But it seems that add_subdirectory doesn't also import variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For expanding the scope of a variable inside a subdirectory, use the `PARENT_SCOPE` option of `set`. For example, you can test that if you have

```
# CMakeLists.txt
set(SRCS main.c)
add_subdirectory(foo)
message(${SRCS})
```

in the root directory and

```
# foo/CMakeLists.txt
set(SRCS ${SRCS} foo.c PARENT_SCOPE)
```

in a subdirectory then it will print `main.c foo.c`, i.e., the variable is correctly imported into the base CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Does this work for any depth? Or do I need to do this for every parent folder.

Comment: The scope propagates upwards only one level. In an intermediate-level CMakeLists.txt, you at least need to have `set(SRCS ${SRCS} PARENT_SCOPE)`, which should be preceded by any `add_subdirectory` commands.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to use the *object library* feature of CMake. You still can but doesn't need to organise your CMake script into subdirectories:

```
add_library(lib1 OBJECT <srcs>)
add_library(lib2 OBJECT <srcs>)
...
add_library(mainlib $<TARGET_OBJECTS:lib1> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:lib2>)
```

You can set different compile flags for each object library:

```
target_include_directories(lib1 PRIVATE incl-dir-for-lib1)
target_compile_definitions(lib2 PRIVATE def-for-lib2)
```

You still need to set link libraries on your main library:

```
target_link_libraries(mainlib PRIVATE deps-of-lib1 deps-of-lib2)
```

Related documentation: [Object Libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#object-libraries)